I need help converting times above 24 hrs to an actual time format from a decimal format
Currently I receive time data in hours like this, and they are automatically sent to me from a report.
46.5
39.8
15.3
41.5
42.0
And I need the output to be in hh:mm:ss format, example below, for a program that I already have made and can't edit.
46:30:00
39:48:00
15:18:00
41:30:00
42:00:00
Is there any way to accomplish that?
I have been trying to accomplish this with formatting but I keep getting way to many hours, like 1000 instead of 40s.
Thank yall in advance for he help!

Divide by 24 and apply a custom number format: [h]:mm:ss.

Just to make @BigBen's comment an answer to hopefully close out this question.
Time in Excel is a decimal part of the integer day.  As in 1.5 would be 36 hours.  So to take the integer hour to a decimal that Excel can use we need to divide by 24, as there are 24 hours in one day.
=A1/24

Then we simply format the output [h]:mm:ss and it will show it correctly.


You could add a named function for the method suggested by BigBen:
Use the Name Manager in Excel - Microsoft Support
For example, with
LAMBDA function - Microsoft Support in Excel for Microsoft 365,
define  fmt_dec_hours as
=LAMBDA(decimal_hours, MAP(decimal_hours, LAMBDA(dh, IFERROR(TEXT(dh / 24, "[h]:mm:ss"), dh))))


then use it with single cells, ranges or arrays:
=fmt_dec_hours(A1:A5)


